# Nativescript ListView onItemLoading event

Tags: nativescript

I'm using the built-in ListView and have the following setup.

```
<ListView items="{{ myItems }}" itemLoading="onItemLoading" itemTemplateSelector="onTemplateSelector">
<ListView.itemTemplates>
  <template key="even">
    <Label text="{{ age }}" style.backgroundColor="white" />
  </template>
  <template key="odd">
    <Label text="{{ age }}" style.backgroundColor="gray" />
  </template>
</ListView.itemTemplates>
```

During the onLoadingEvent - where each item is about to be loaded, I look at the args.view and it's always undefined. I would have expected it to be the full template view structure - depending on what onTemplateSelector returned.

Looking at some more of the documentation and it seems that if it's undefined then you've got to create the entire structure within code.

Did I miss something? If no, then what's the purpose of allowing the template item definitions (e.g. Label in my sample code).

Comment: A work-around could be - can I pass an xml definition in a string to a function and have it create the views in the xml. This in {N} w/o Angular.

Answer (score 1):

If you just do

`<ListView.itemTemplates>
  <Label text="{{ age }}" style.backgroundColor="gray" />
</ListView.itemTemplates>`

That will work fine. I'm not sure what your `<template>` element is.